# Combine duplicate rows and SUM QTY by Time stamp

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm new to SQL and I am trying to combine duplicate `TRK_ID` to one single row and SUM the `IN_QTY` if the HRS column is the same time stamp.
Can someone please help me.
Thank you!!

Current SQL Code:

```
Select TRK_ID, IN_QTY, TRUNC(LOT_DTTM, 'hh') as HRS
from TRK_ID_LOT
WHERE facility in 'DP1DM5'
and trk_id like ('AE%')
and lot_dttm > sysdate - 1
```

SQL Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try grouping by your `TRK_ID` and `HRS` before finding the sum of `IN_QTY` eg

```sql
Select TRK_ID, SUM(IN_QTY) as IN_QTY, TRUNC(LOT_DTTM, 'hh') as HRS
from TRK_ID_LOT
WHERE facility in 'DP1DM5'
and trk_id like ('AE%')
and lot_dttm > sysdate - 1
GROUP BY TRK_ID, TRUNC(LOT_DTTM, 'hh')
```